# Clover Alternative?

Tags: windows, productivity

Clover is a program that wraps windows explorer and allows multiple tabs, and is hands-down my favorite productivity program. Well it used to be, lately however, I have been experiencing severe performance problems on windows 10. I am in need of a replacement program. I have looked around but all of the ones I saw were a complete overhauls for windows explorer, or they were no longer supported. Seriously, all I need is the ability to have tabs and bookmarks, is that so hard?

Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: You didn't say what kind of "severe performance problems" you're experiencing, but it wouldn't be at all related to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3fh1ok/has_anybody_found_a_clover_equivalent_for_windows/), would it?

Comment: I have not personally used any of these, which is why I am not posting this as an answer, but [here are some possible alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/clover/).

Comment: @JohnY That thread helped, I'm now running clover in windows 7 compatibility mode and it seems to be working much better. The performance problems I was getting were clover taking around 15 seconds to do anything i.e. open window, navigate - on an ssd.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) is the solution you are looking for.

Features:

- With the option to save to the registry or a configuration file,
  Explorer++ is completely **portable**
- Tabbed browsing for easy management of multiple folders
- Display window shows previews of files as they are selected
- Easy-to-remember keyboard shortcuts for quick navigation
- Customizable user interface
- Full drag-and-drop support with other applications, including Windows
  Explorer
- Advanced file operations such as merging and splitting supported
- Change file dates and attributes
- Save a directory listing
- Bookmark tabs
- Search for files using their name and attributes
- Switch between icon, list, detail, thumbnail and tile view
- Filter files

[image]

Although the website is not updated, the project is alive and versions are still [coming out](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/derceg/explorerplusplus/history).

Here you can [download the last version](https://github.com/derceg/explorerplusplus#latest-builds).